# Ambiguous Date format

Tags: database, date

I have a database which keeps dates as a number like 1488950859, and when I run the software which associated to the DB, it shows this date : 2017-March 08   08:27 AM
another example is :

1395208154  = 2014 March 19, 8:49 AM

anyone can give me a hand and reveal this mysterious format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it..
this is called Unix timestamp, it is no. of seconds since standard epoch of 1st Jan 1970.

to return it to ordinary date format , use below function

```
Public Function UnixToDateTime(ByVal strUnixTime As String) As DateTime

        Dim nTimestamp As Double = strUnixTime
        Dim nDateTime As System.DateTime = New System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        nDateTime = nDateTime.AddSeconds(nTimestamp)

        Return nDateTime
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are storing date in a column of type nvarchar because when you save date in nvarchar column it converts into number.